# spin density file job.scfr did not generate even after keeping the keepdens command

Tags: orca

I was running some calculations to generate the spin density plots for some of my intermediates. In some cases orca failed to create a file which should contain the spin density information, named as job.scfr.This happened even after keeping the command keepdens

I was expecting a file which contain the spin density information from orca